# Get files names from S3 bucket and directory without directory name?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

I have connected to S3 and got all files in my S3 bucket foo and from folder poo.
All my files are in `S3://foo/poo`.

Running this code returns:

```
[i.key for i in s3_resource.Bucket(foo).objects.filter(Delimiter='/', Prefix='poo/')]
```

I am getting:

```
['poo/',
 'poo/a.png',
 'poo/b.png',
 'poo/c.png',
.....]
```

How can I get rid of `poo/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[i.key for i in s3_resource.Bucket("foo").objects.filter(Delimiter='/', Prefix='poo/') if i.key != 'poo/']
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

use rsplit with max splits equal to 1 and take the 2nd value

```
[i.key.rsplit('/', 1)[1] 
 for i in s3_resource.Bucket(foo).objects.filter(Delimiter='/', Prefix='poo/')
 if i.key.rsplit('/', 1)[1] != '']
```

should give

```
['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png', ...]
```

Comment: But I still get the `''`, is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Sure there is, just add a not-equals filter . See updated answer